# Why does Directory.Exists("....../.../////....///.../") return true?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Well, the question is in the title.
Why does `Directory.Exists("....../.../////....///.../")` return **true**? That directory **does not exist**.
Is there any alternative to that?

I wrote a ValidationRule for TextBoxes (WPF) requiring a directory. Here's the code:

```
public class DirectoryExistsValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var fieldIsRequiredValidationResult = new ValidationResult(false, "Field is required");
        if(value == null)
        {
            return fieldIsRequiredValidationResult;
        }
        else if (value.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            return fieldIsRequiredValidationResult;
        }
        else
        {
            return Directory.Exists(value.ToString())
            ? ValidationResult.ValidResult
            : new ValidationResult(false, "The path doesn't exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

And it returns `ValidationResult.ValidResult` when I input something like `"....../.../////....///.../"`

The current directory is (*edited*): `C:\Users\username\source\repos\projectname\projectname\bin\Debug`

There is 2 folders and some files in the "Debug" folder. In those 2 folders are only files, no more folders.

[Directory (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.8) says

> Ensure that your paths are well-formed when using methods that accept a path string. For more information see [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.8).

That page says

> For more information on file path formats on Windows, see [File path formats on Windows systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats).

The section [Trim characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#trim-characters) says

> A segment of three or more periods is not normalized and is actually a valid file/directory name.

So the four parts of multiple dots in my string each represents a potentially valid directory, but none of them exists on my hard disk. Still, the result is  **true**.

Comment: More than two dots is the same as two dots (parent). More than one slash is the same as one slash. This is the same as `../../../../`, or 4 layers up from current.

Comment: Interesting. It's `true` in console .net framework application and  `false` in console .net core one.

Comment: I think this should be passthrough to OS, and handled differently in .net and .net-core. On windows, this ends up calling kernel32 method GetFileAttributes (ex). You can follow the exact calls from: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/60dc59b8eb93ca6a7fe18e1269949b7af7e5c3bd/src/libraries/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Directory.cs#L53 -- The point is, this is not really a C# issue.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I just tested it out on LinqPad. I should also mention that if `..` us used on the root directory, it will just resolve to the root directory without raising an error.

Comment: @Sinatr I just tested with .NetFramework 4.7.2 and `....../.../////....///.../` returned false while `../../../../` returned true.

Comment: [The official definition is here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats) According to that, each consecutive double-dot takes you up one directory, while single-dots will be ignored. This means that for an odd number of consecutive dots, the last dot is ignored. This also matches the output I get when I try this and check the result with `Path.GetFullPath()`

Comment: For some reason this was closed so I can't post an answer, but to work around you can write a custom validation method that iteratively calls `GetDirectoryName` until the input is the same as the output. Something like `while (s != s2) { s = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(s2); s2 = s; if (s == string.Empty) { break; } }`

Comment: @ThomasWeller Ah yes, indeed it does - that's also covered by the official definition.

Comment: Is there any way to make the `Exists()` method to search only the absolute path?

Comment: Unable to replicate on .NET 5. Not going to check on Framework since this question is not tagged as such. Therefore, voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: I can reproduce in .NET Framework 4.8.4341.0